# MS SQL How to field add auto increment dependent on another field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, increment, procedure

For example, there is a table

```
 int type
 int number
 int value
```

How to make that when inserting a value into a table
indexing started from 1 for different types.

```
type 1 => number 1,2,3...
type 2 => number 1,2,3...
```

That is, it will look like this.

| type | number | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | - |
| 1 | 2 | - |
| 1 | 3 | - |
| 2 | 1 | - |
| 1 | 4 | - |
| 2 | 2 | - |
| 3 | 1 | - |
| 6 | 1 | - |
| 1 | 5 | - |
| 2 | 3 | - |
| 6 | 2 | - |

---

Special thanks to @Larnu.

As a result, in my case, the best solution would be to create a table for each type.

Comment: Do you have a column in the table that can be used for `order by` to sort the results?

Comment: An `IDENTITY`/`SEQUENCE` can't be dependant of the value of another column. You would either need to use multiple `SEQUENCE`s and use the correct one for the value of `type` (which won't scale), or you can use `ROW_NUMBER` at the time you `SELECT` the data (likely better solution). You might to move this logic to a `VIEW`, so that you can then `SELECT` against the `VIEW` and get your incrementing value.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I need auto increment, not result display :(

Comment: @Larnu It's still a little different. I need exactly the automatic installation of "number". Display does not interest me. And unless it is impossible in a script of creation of the table. to specify conditions for a field? An example of how we add a clustered index. But anyway, thanks for the reply.

Comment: As I stated, an `IDENTITY`/`SEQUENCE` can't be dependent on the value of a column; you can have it check what the value of another column is in the `INSERT` and then use the next available value for that other column. In regards to a "castrated index", I have no idea what you mean by that (I don't think castrated means what you think it does).

Comment: Basically, from what I understand, at least, what you want is a row_number partitioned by type, ordered by... what, exactly? the order the rows were inserted into the table? what if you insert more than one row in a single statement?

Comment: @Larnu I understand that specifically [IDENTITY / SEQUENCE] cannot work like this, since the value must be unique. Oh, that's a typo, already fixed "castrated index" => "clustered index"

Comment: @ZoharPeled This is exactly what I need. In this process, inserting more than 1 at a time is excluded.

Comment: Now I am getting the TVP table and making calls to get the maximum index for the type and inserting a new row. This is done for each element in the TVP. And I want to get rid of getting the maximum index for a specific type.

Comment: The very fact the new values depend on existing data means you need a *query*. You'll have to post a concrete instead of an abstract question though - in general, the best option is to use `ROW_NUMBER()` in a query instead of pre-calculating a row value. Or calculate the value in the insertion script, eg retrieving a value from different SEQUENCE objects based on type

Comment: TBH, I kind of like the phrase "castrated index" :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, neither `IDENTITY` nor `SEQUENCE` support the use of another column to denote what "identity set" they should use. You *can* have multiple `SEQUENCE`s which you could use for a single table, however, this doesn't scale. If you are specific limited to 2 or 3 types, for example, you might choose to create 3 `SEQUENCE` objects, and then use a stored procedure to handle your `INSERT` statements. Then, when a user/application wants to `INSERT` data, they call the procedure and that procedure has logic to use the `SEQUENCE` based on the value of the parameter for the `type` column.

As mentioned, however, this doesn't scale well. If you have an undeterminate number of values of `type` then you can't easily handle getting the right `SEQUENCE` and handling new values for `type` would be difficult too. In this case, you would be better off using a `IDENTITY` and then a `VIEW`. The `VIEW` will use `ROW_NUMBER` to create your identifier, while `IDENTITY` gives you your always incrementing value.

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (id int IDENTITY(1,1),
                            [type] int NOT NULL,
                            number int NULL,
                            [value] int NOT NULL);
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.YourTableView AS
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [type] ORDER BY id ASC) AS Identifier,
           [type],
           number,
           [value]
    FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Then, instead, you query the `VIEW`, not the `TABLE`.

If you need consistency of the column (I name `identifier`) you'll need to also ensure row(s) can't be `DELETE`d from the table. Most likely by adding an `IsDeleted` column to the table defined as a `bit` (with `0` for no deleted, and `1` for deleted), and then you can filter to those rows in the `VIEW`:

```sql
CREATE VIEW dbo.YourTableView AS
    WITH CTE AS(
        SELECT id,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [type] ORDER BY id ASC) AS Identifier,
               [type],
               number,
               [value],
               IsDeleted
        FROM dbo.YourTable)
    SELECT id,
           Identifier,
           [type],
           number,
           [value]
    FROM CTE
    WHERE IsDeleted = 0;
```

You could, if you wanted, even handle the `DELETE`s on the `VIEW` (the `INSERT` and `UPDATE`s would be handled implicitly, as it's an updatable `VIEW`):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_YourTableView_Delete ON dbo.YourTableView 
INSTEAD OF DELETE AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE YT
    SET IsDeleted = 1
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
         JOIN deleted d ON d.id = YT.id;
END;
GO
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kEzO5lZz)

---

For completion, if you wanted to use different `SEQUENCE` object, it would look like this. Notice that this *does not* scale easily. I have to `CREATE` a `SEQUENCE` for every value of `Type`. As such, for a small, and known, range of values this would be a solution, but if you are going to end up with more value for `type` or already have a large range, this ends up not being feasible pretty quickly:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (identifier int NOT NULL,
                            [type] int NOT NULL,
                            number int NULL,
                            [value] int NOT NULL);

CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.YourTable_Type1
    START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.YourTable_Type2
    START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.YourTable_Type3
    START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

GO

CREATE PROC dbo.Insert_YourTable @Type int, @Number int = NULL, @Value int AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Identifier int;
    IF @Type = 1
        SELECT @Identifier = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.YourTable_Type1;
    IF @Type = 2
        SELECT @Identifier = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.YourTable_Type2;
    IF @Type = 3
        SELECT @Identifier = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.YourTable_Type3;

    INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (identifier,[type],number,[value])
    VALUES(@Identifier, @Type, @Number, @Value);

END;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for these options. Especially for the last one.
But from what I've seen, I understand. What would be the best solution to create independent tables with their own type...

Comment: And yes, I only have 3 types. there will be no other variations.

Comment: If you did that, I *hope* you don't need to query all the types at the same time, @ZLoo . You wouldn't be able to do `SELECT * FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE [Type] IN (1,3)` anymore, and queries like `SELECT * FROM dbo.SomeaAble ST JOIN dbo.YourTable YT ON ST.[Type] = AT.[Type]` would be impossible.

Comment: *"And yes, I only have 3 types."* Your question has 4, as an FYI (1, 2, 3, and 6).

Comment: I need a concept. and I wrote more types for a more understandable example